# Why do the c++ files in my folder not show when I try to open them in Visual Studios?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to open up a pre-existing folder in visual studios that has several c++ files. When I look at them on my desktop it shows the files as there, but when I go to open them in visual studios they no longer show up in the folder. I am using a virtual PC and this folder is one I opened from a zip file if those factors make a difference.

Folder outside of VS:
[image: Folder outside of VS]

vs. Folder inside VS:
[image: Folder inside VS]

Comment: I am trying to select a folder, but it appears empty when I use it. When I open that folder no header or solution files appear in my project.

Comment: Visual Studio is looking for a Visual Studio project file, something not in the folder in the first place. You will have to make a C++ project and then add your source code files to that project.

Comment: You may not know what a "project file" is.  You can see in your screenshot that Visual Studio is looking for a _Project file_.  And none of the files in that folder are project files.

Comment: Vscode can do this but visual studios isn't

Answer (score 0):

Normally adding a project requires a folder to contain the .sln file. If you don't have a .sln file, you have to create a C++ project. We could open the project by selecting the .sln file to be added in Open>Project/Solution, just like the picture I uploaded.

[image]